# Frequently changing of accepted answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

There was a **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889828/replace-image-source/30890207#30890207)** for which I **[answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30890207/2065039)**, but within a span of 30 minutes the OP accepted my answer twice and accepted another answer twice on request of the the guy who answered.

The OP might think that they can accept both answers, but that will definitely causes change in reputation for both.
I feel my answer is better than the currently accepted answer, because I've given a demo and explained what the issue was.

Now Stack Overflow says that the better answer should be accepted. But when these kinds of serial changes occur, it definitely makes the guy who provided a better answer feel bad, since there is time and effort spent to answer the same.

These sorts of actions might discourage one to not answer an OP's question who is new to the site.

The OP might be new to Stack Overflow, but these kind of actions should be well known by the OP. Shouldn't there be some sort of mechanism or feature in Stack Overflow to stop this?

Comment: There is a clear tooltip over the accept button - no need in flashy red banners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not really. The OP is allowed to change the accepted answer to whatever they wish whenever they wish. If frequent changing is the result of pestering the OP for acceptance of an answer, that needs to be addressed. But there is no problem with the feature itself.

Comment: Agree!! he did not pester either but just based on a comment the OP changed the answer and if addressed again OP might switch it which I don't wanna happen. At least someone has to address it properly right?

Comment: I left a comment for the user. He probably just meant to inform the OP. No harm done overall. And not something that really requires additional features to address.

Comment: That was just nicely handled.. :) Thanks @Bart. Accepting the answer.. :) By posting this question I do not want my answer to be accepted one, I just wanted better one to be accepted.. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't be there some sort of mechanism or feature in Stack Overflow
>   to stop this?

I don't think any change is necessary, nor would be a good thing.

You could, for example, allow OP to change their initial choice of accepted answer within 20 mins (as normal) then impose a limit on total changes and time delay.

Such as after initial accept, can only change it 2 times per hour.

---

However:

I'm just not sure that "serial accepted answer changes" happens very often to be honest.
"Most" users are pretty clear on which answer helped them the most, and a fair handful don't even bother accepting.

Also, a user might genuinely need to change their accept outside whatever boundaries a new limiting system would introduce.
Perhaps an accepted answer was changed for the worse, or non-accepted was improved drastically, etc.
And any kind of limiting of accepting of answers "could" be problematic.

---

Also, as @ShadowWizard stated, "There is a clear tooltip over the accept button". With that, and the Help Center and other info like FAQs and Meta posts etc, I think we have the info out there for anyone who cares enough to look.
For example, someone unsure which answer to choose will find various Meta posts about "how to choose an answer" etc.

Comment: That's the problem with newbie on SO. They might not read documentation thoroughly which leads to all these sort of doubts!!